# Angular Modules vs Modular Website Design

Tags: javascript, angular, design-patterns

Angular is a framework for building Modular client applications. Do those Angular modules have anything in common with modules used in Modular Website design (which I get from the designer).

I mean, when I'm getting the modular website design (created by an designer), may I build an Angular modules according to the modules from the website design? Or, I need to take a step back and to design my own Angular modules according to the website design?

I'm currently working as an web developer. But,from time to time, before starting the development, I also have to create an website mockup design. So, the question is, do I have to learn Modular Website design concepts to ease on myself afterwards while implementing the designing an Angular framework?

Comment: I barely understand your "modular" concept. But in Angular/AngularJS you would usually start with [**functionalities first**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/8495123) and then build a website around it.

Comment: *Does those Angular modules has anything in common with modules used in Modular Website design* - the word 'module'. Modular design can correspond to Angular components. It's dev's decision how Angular modules should be organized.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what actual meaning of modular programming in angular. As most people think we create modules for lazy loading but this is not case. Modules are independent part of your application which may or may not depend on other modules.

You organise your application in modules to easily work on that. You design your modules to organise your code in a proper way.

Let say your application have someFeature1 and someFeature2 then it's all depends on dependability of these two feature that will these features will be in two different modules or in one. 
Always Try to refactor your code in modules. This will make easy to maintain your application. A module can also have child child modules and this is very good practice.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I will suggest that you should learn about Modular Website design concepts. This will make it much easier for you to work on the website, or else you will get stuck in many doubts which will make designing a long and boring work for you.